# Cant import file in typescript in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, import

I am getting much errors like :
Compiled with problems:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/SearchSMS/Letters.tsx 122:71-81

export 'default' (imported as 'ChatWindow') was not found in './ChatWindow.js' (possible exports: __esModule)
```

But my PHPStorm IDE doesnt show my any error. And i made import properly.
Like :

```
import ChatWindow, {messageI} from "./ChatWindow";
or
import ChatWindow, {messageI} from "./ChatWindow.js";
```

```
export default function ChatWindow(props: propsI) {
...
}
```

my package.json looks like :

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.13.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "ts-migrate": "^0.1.35",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json looks like

```
{
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }],


    "target": "ES2018",                             
    "jsx": "preserve",                              

    "module": "CommonJS",                           

    "outDir": "./build",                            

    "esModuleInterop": true,                        
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,       

    "strict": true,                                 

    "skipLibCheck": true,
     //and others commented settings                       
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "lib": ["esnext"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  }
}
```

I tried to move from js to typescript in my project.
Actually, i even don't see compiled files when i delete and try.
tsc
or
npx tsc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cause of my problem. This was because "ts-migrate" package build
every single ts-tsx file right in same place. And when i import the file, it gets imported not from ts file, but from bad or old built js file.
Imagine you have Home.ts and Home.js file, and when you make

```
import Home from './Home';
```

you get import from Home.js, but not Home.ts